# ogr2ogr imports GML data (not from OSM) to Postgis but without the other_tags "hstore"-column

Tags: postgis, postgresql, ogr2ogr, xml, gml

**The problem**

I'm encountering some issue trying to use `ogr2ogr` to import some GML input data (***not OSM***) into Postgres. I'm trying to use `COLUMN_TYPES=other_tags=hstore` to store all the fields not referenced in the `-select` option in a hstore-type-column.

The data gets imported, but there is no column of type hstore in the resulting table containing the rest of the fields...

**The command I try to use**

```
ogr2ogr -f PostgreSQL "PG:dbname=rem host=192.168.XX.YY user=XXXXX password=XXXXXXX" test.xml -append -nln public.t_test_ogr2ogr_v26 -select gml_id,identifier,beginnt -lco COLUMN_TYPES=other_tags=hstore -nlt geometry
```

**The current result**

```
'ogc_fid';'wkb_geometry';'gml_id';'identifier';'beginnt'
1;'0102000000030...';'DERPTL4a0000zZFt';'urn:adv:oid:DERPTL4a0000zZFt';'2015-11-25T14:28:13Z'
2;'0102000000020...';'DERPTL4a0000AIzO';'urn:adv:oid:DERPTL4a0000AIzO';'2015-11-25T14:28:13Z'
3;'0102000000020...';'DERPTL4a0000AIzP';'urn:adv:oid:DERPTL4a0000AIzP';'2015-11-25T14:28:13Z'
```

**The expected result**

The same as above with an additional column of type hstore.

```
'ogc_fid';'wkb_geometry';'gml_id';'identifier';'beginnt';'tags'
1;'0102000000030...';'DERPTL4a0000zZFt';'urn:adv:oid:DERPTL4a0000zZFt';'2015-11-25T14:28:13Z';'"anlass"=>"3000", "advStandard"=>"DLM50", ...'
2;'0102000000020...';'DERPTL4a0000AIzO';'urn:adv:oid:DERPTL4a0000AIzO';'2015-11-25T14:28:13Z';'"anlass"=>"3000", "advStandard"=>"DLM50", ...'
3;'0102000000020...';'DERPTL4a0000AIzP';'urn:adv:oid:DERPTL4a0000AIzP';'2015-11-25T14:28:13Z';'"anlass"=>"3000", "advStandard"=>"DLM50", ...'
```

**Test Input GML-File (55 KB)**

https://haste.zertrin.org/raw/tafomudifi

(if needed, the XSD-files can be found here: http://repository.gdi-de.org/schemas/adv/nas/6.0ea/ )

**Corresponding gfs file created automatically by ogr2ogr**

https://haste.zertrin.org/raw/diwowideji

Comment: There may be other issues but at least you do not select the tags at all now `-select gml_id,identifier,beginnt`

Comment: @user30184 `tags` isn't a field in the input data. This is an exemple of a column name for the HSTORE-column gathering the rest of the fields from the input data through the option `COLUMN_TYPES=other_tags=hstore`

Comment: Are you sure that it works like that with any other GDAL driver than the OSM driver http://www.gdal.org/drv_osm.html? I am rather sure that it doesn't and the virtual other_tags and all_tags field are available only from OSM data and osmconf.ini file.

Comment: I'm not sure indeed. This could explain why the virtual fields don't appear. I'm currently looking at http://www.gdal.org/drv_nas.html to see if there is more to be done in that direction.

Comment: Your source GML is rather complicated to be used for testing. It seems to contain 10 layers which may all have different schema. I would first extract one layer and tell GDAL to create hstore from one attribute.